# How to create user manual in Android App?

Tags: android, hint, user-manual

I saw a beautiful user manual some Apps.There,when user enters to a new page,most of it's surface is gray,except of an area that user must be click it.Also,here user sees some hints.For example like this image:

[image]

When user clickes on lighter area,next hint will be shown,for example like this:

[image]

Now my question is:How we can create user manual or user hints,like these?

Comment: Man those things are UGLY!

Comment: @varevarao Why those are UGLY?Those can help user to know flow of App.

Comment: Err.. I was talking 'bout the screenshots.